# Tensorflow 2.0 version clash with scikit-learn 0.21 with conda

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

In order to install Tensorflow 2.0, I updated all my packages in conda using `conda update --all`. I later realised that although  I got TF2.0, my scikit-learn module was not there. While trying to install it manually, I got a message that TF2.0 will be downgraded to 1.15([Downgrade message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgRof.jpg)). Is there any way I can keep TF2.0 and scikit-learn together?

My python version is 3.6.9

I have all of them in the base environment. Will installing everything again in another environment resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe you can try a new conda environment with Python 3.7 and then install TF 2.0 and Scikit learn?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install scikit-learn`? pip normally does not downgrade any other packages.